# I cannot apply custom Script plugin

Tags: android, gradle

I have made `buildsystem` directory and within this directory I have created file which is library.gradle and config.gradle file.code is given below:

config.gradle

```
ext.configuration = [

  applicationId       : bicker.techfour.com.bicker,
  versionMajor                : 1,
  versionMinor                : 0,
  versionPatch                : 2,
  versionClassifier           : "",
  minimumSdkVersion           : 14,
  compileSdkVersion           : 23,
  targetSdkVersion            : 23,
  buildToolsVersion           : "23.0.2"
]

def configuration = ext.configuration;

ext.buildVersionCode = {
    return configuration.minimumSdkVersion * 10000000 + configuration.versionMajor * 10000 + configuration.versionMinor * 100 + configuration.versionPatch
}

ext.buildVersionName = {
    String versionName = ext.buildVersionNameWithoutClassifier();
    if (configuration.versionClassifier != null && !configuration.versionClassifier.isEmpty()) {
        versionName = versionName + "-" + configuration.versionClassifier
    }
    return versionName;
}
```

library.gradle

```
ext.version = [
    support          : "23.2.1",
    rxjava           : "1.1.0",
    rxandroid        : "1.1.0",

]

def version = ext.version;

ext.library = [
    support_compat   :
            "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${version.support}",
    support_design   : "com.android.support:design:${version.support}",
    rxjava           :
            "io.reactivex:rxjava:${version.rxjava}",
    rxandroid        :
            "io.reactivex:rxandroid:${version.rxandroid}",
]
```

Now app.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 

{

compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "bicker.techfour.com.bicker"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "version"
            applicationId = "bicker.techfour.com.bicker"
            versionName = "1.0"
        }

        mock {
            dimension "version"
            applicationId = "bicker.techfour.com.bicker"
            versionName = "1.0"
        }

    }


}



apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/buildsystem/library.gradle"
def library = ext.library
dependencies {
    compile                 fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile                 "${library.support_compat}"
    compile                 "${library.support_design}"
    compile                 "${library.rxjava}"
    compile                 "${library.rxandroid}"
    // rest of dependencies
}
apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/buildsystem/config.gradle"
def configuration = ext.configuration

android {
    compileSdkVersion configuration.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion configuration.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId configuration.applicationId
        minSdkVersion configuration.minimumSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion configuration.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode buildVersionCode()
        versionName buildVersionName()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: actually i got the error in event log file The system cannot find the path specified) of library and config file , is it right way to fetch the file in app.gradle file from external director file .i have created directory inside the app -> build-> buildsystem->library.gradle: config.gradle .

Comment: the localtion of your `buildsystem` directory seems wrong: you should have this directory at the same level as `app` directory, not under `app/build`.  then  `apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/buildsystem/config.gradle"` should work

Comment: C:/Users/Admin/AndroidStudioProjects/Bicker
.gradle
.idea
app
app/build
app/buildsystem
app/libs
app/src
app/src/androidTest
app/src/main


app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
app/src/test
app/.gitignore
app/app.iml
app/build.gradle
app/proguard-rules.pro
gradle
.gitignore
Bicker.iml
build.gradle
gradle.properties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
local.properties
settings.gradle ( this is my structure )

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear how is your project layout from your question and comment, but I think you should have something like:

```
$rootProjectDir
    |- build.gradle
    |
    |-app/
    |   |- build.gradle
    |  
    |-buildsystem/
    |    |- config.gradle
    |    |- library.gradle
```

Then in you app `build.gradle` file you can include the two gradle files as you did:

```
apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/buildsystem/config.gradle"
apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/buildsystem/library.gradle"
```

Comment: C:/Users/Admin/AndroidStudioProjects/Bicker
|
.gradle
|
.idea
|
app
|
buildsystem
|
gradle
|
.gitignore
|
Bicker.iml
|
build.gradle
|
gradle.properties
|
gradlew
|
gradlew.bat
|
local.properties
|
settings.gradle